# Trying to use lambda for the first time and the code doesn't compile

Tags: eclipse, lambda, java-8

I trying to use the lambda expressions in Java-8 using eclipse IDE.

I took this example from some youtube tutorial which worked well there, but in my code it doesn't and it gave me this error.

I tried to add `Integer` before the `value` and it still the same.

How can I solve it?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're using a recent version of Eclipse which supports Java 8 language features?

Comment: My eclipse version is: `Kepler Service Release 2, Build id: 20140224-0627`, seems like it's too old.

Comment: Yup, that sounds like it's the problem. I suggest you delete this question for the moment - you can undelete it later if that turns out not to be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the latest version of eclipse from here:https://eclipse.org/downloads/

Take the Luna version.